# How to restore local folder contents after first git clone

Tags: macos, github

I started a new github repository online, and cloned it to my computer. I accidentally cloned it to an existing folder, and thus all existing files were deleted and replaced with the files from my repository.

Is there any way to restore the old files from that folder with a git 'trick', or should I really be worried and use a data recovery utility?

thanks for your answer.

p.s.: the files from the overwritten folder are not in my recycling bin either. I'm on a mac OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time machine is your best bet, or some other backup.

Git only knows about files that it specifically tracks. If it's overwritten local files, it wasn't tracking them, so it can do nothing about restoring them for you.

Sorry.